# How to find items not in a table

Tags: mysql

My database has,

```
mysql> select * from peeps;
+-------+
| name  |
+-------+
| tom   |
| dick  |
| harry |
+-------+
```

I want to write a sql statement to return a result set of users not in that table.

```
sql ????  where name in ( 'dave', 'tom')
```

I want a result set which returns 'dave'.  The answer can't return 'harry'.  I'm not keen on creating a new temporary table, can this be dont in a single statement.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this work for you? It returns `dave` as requested.

```
SELECT a.name
FROM
    (SELECT 'dave' AS name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'tom' AS name) a
LEFT JOIN peeps b ON b.name = a.name
WHERE b.name IS NULL
```

**Result**

```
| NAME |
--------
| dave |
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90186/1)